# Ubuntu Core on RPi 2,

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I am trying to boot 16.04 Ubuntu Core on my Pi 2. I have downloaded the image and 'dd' it to my sdcard. It won't boot. I get solid red and green lights and no signal out my HDMI port.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `sync` after `dd` or try another SD card.